# (a) Can $\sin(x+y)/(x+y)$ be made continuous by suitably defining it at (0,0)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

(a) Can $\sin(x+y)/(x+y)$ be made continuous by suitably defining it at (0,0)?

(b) Can $xy/(x^2 + y^2)$ be made continuous by suitably defining it at (0,0)?

(c) Prove that $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, $(x, y) \to ye^x + \sin(x) + (xy)^4$ is continuous.

---

Attempt

(a) let $t = x + y$

$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{sin(x+y)}{x+y} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{sin(t)}{t} = 1$

is continuous at $0,0$

(b) Using $y = mx$

$\frac{x \cdot mx}{x^2 + (mx)^2} = \frac{m}{1+m^2}$

Not continuous since it's dependent on value of m

(c)

let $y = x, x = 0$

$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} ye^x + sin(x) + xy^4 = 0$

therefore continuous

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) You forgot to notice that the function is not defined on the line $x=-y$. But your reasoning outside of this subdomain is correct.

(b) Is correct

(c) You were asked to prove that the function is continuous **everywhere**, not that it it's limit is defined at $(0,0)$